# Why is this hook for a ACF Multisite Cross-Site Select field causing issues?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, multisite

I have the code below to populate an ACF Select field from a Custom Post Type on another Site in a Multisite Network.
(CPT = 'cta', fieldname = 'site1_cta')

It works, ie it populates the select and allows the rest of ACF to work it's magic but it causes issues:
One issue is that if the Select Field is positioned in the Side the content of **some** fields in the main body disappear.

So it works from the point of view of development but its not ready to move to a live site.

Can anyone see anything in this code that would cause issues with other ACF Field Groups (or anything else)

```
function acf_load_cta( $field ) {

    $field['choices'] = array();
    $language = pll_current_language();

    switch_to_blog(1);

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'cta',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'lang' => $language,
    );

    $page_query = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($page_query->have_posts()) {
        while ($page_query->have_posts()) {
            $page_query->the_post();
            $field['choices'][get_the_ID()] = get_the_title();
        }
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();
    restore_current_blog();
    // return the field
    return $field;
}

add_filter('acf/load_field/name=site1_cta', 'acf_load_cta', 999, 1);
```